# Colored git output piped to sponge

Tags: pipe, colors, git

`git` will color it's output. Staged changes are green and deleted files are red for example.
I have a script running several `git` commands in parallel and I use `sponge` to get a nicer output.

But using `sponge` removes the colors, is there a way to change that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now that I knew what to look for, I found the answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16073708/4500798):

```
git -c color.ui=always -c color.status=always status | sponge
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can force `git` to output colour codes. For many `git` subcommands, you can add the `--color` option:

```
git log --color | sponge
```

For others, you’ll need to configure the colour output using configuration directives; either per command:

```
git -c color.status=always status | sponge
```

or for good in one of the configuration files:

```
git config --global color.status always
git status | sponge
```

(By default, `git` disables colour output when its output is sent somewhere other than a terminal. If you want to set the `color` directive for `--color` compatible subcommands, you need to use the `color.ui` key: `git config --global color.ui always`.)

Comment: That doesn't work for `git status`

Comment: I’ve updated my answer; I didn’t realise you were looking for `status` (although the green and red references should have given me the hint).